What happens when the number of coin-flips are restricted in probabilistic Turing machines
If all probabilistic Turing machines make at most $\mathcal{O}(\log n)$
number of coin-flips before termination when run on an input of length n , or such machines can always be constructed for deciding a language which is known to be in BPP, would this imply that P=BPP? If it does, how to prove that?
